# Revealing NFT after whole collection is sold (ECR721)

Tags: nft

Is it possible to only reveal the NFT's after the whole collection have been sold?
If so, any documents I can read or videos I can watch?

Thanks
Arnold

Answer (score 0):

Can you expand a little bit more on what you are going for?

Are you looking at doing something where let's say you have 100 NFTs on offer and then only after all 100 have been sold does the image of each of them become active?

If so, you could do this by having the metadata in the `token_uri` get updated when the last one is sold. That would somewhat go against the standard immutability of NFT metadata though.

You could do it another way and build a contract that allowed people to transfer funds and essentially get on a list that when it hit x-amount of sales, it minted and airdropped everybody their NFTs. If you were doing this on the Ethereum network you'd get stung pretty hard on gas fees though.

Anyway, let me know a bit more info and i can try and suggest a few more options.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  

I've done a bit of digging and came across this NFT website: [CCB](https://crazycyberbunny.com)

If you scroll a bit down you can see that you can mint NFT's from their website, I've learned that this is called "lazy minting" and that all fees are covered by the buyer.

Now if you scroll down a bit more to their FAQ, the 2nd question: "How do I know what CCB I get?".

I am not sure how they're handling everything, but this is basically the exact same thing I'd like to do. The "blind sale" part, not the whole game part. Really appreciate any help on this.